# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I'm working on a project with Azure functions. The function works correctly until I run Scaffold command to create the entities and dbContext. I installed Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstraction and the problem still exist. The project uses .NET 6 and Visual Studio 2022.

> error:  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

I want the function runs.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. With the information provided nobody is able to help you with your question. Take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing a version that starts with 6 (for instance v6.0.3), if you haven't already.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I found that at the moment Azure functions only work on Net 6 using versions with 6. So you are right and was useful thanks.